# Resize EFI partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, grub-efi

I wanted to try to install `Arch Linux` on my laptop, i have `ubuntu 22.04` and `windows 10` installed on my machine. But i can't install `Arch Linux` because the `EFI` on `/boot/efi` is full: `100 MB` used.

So i don't know how to proceed.

-> A list of all files on `/boot/efi`:

> $ sudo ls -l /boot/efi

```
total 49731
drwx------ 4 root root     1024 juin  26  2017  boot-sav
-r-x------ 1 root root      512 août  29  2015  BOOTSECT.BAK
drwx------ 7 root root     1024 janv. 19 22:44  EFI
-rwx------ 1 root root 31416320 mai   25 23:23  initramfs-linux-fallback.img
-rwx------ 1 root root  8989089 mai   25 23:23  initramfs-linux.img
-rwx------ 1 root root       34 janv. 20 15:42  mach_kernel
drwx------ 3 root root     1024 janv. 20 15:42  System
drwx------ 2 root root     1024 août  29  2015 'System Volume Information'
-rwx------ 1 root root 10511904 mai   25 22:33  vmlinuz-linux
```

-> A screenshot of gparted:[image]

Comment: I looked at something similar previously, but it seems a bit risky because for my case i had to resize/move three partitions sda2 sda3 and sda4. All that risk to get about 500MB on sda1, is there another way ?

Comment: Make excellent backup of your data and Windows. [Someone else reported their ESP filling up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410236/how-can-i-expand-the-boot-efi-partition-on-ubuntu-20-04/1410239#1410239) 2 days ago. Look for the underlying cause, such as a UEFI malware. A Commentator wrote their ESP partition (dual boot) only had 42 MB used.

Comment: Your boot-sav folder is from Boot-Repair. It does not normally write into ESP, unless prevented from writing into /var/log. And why are initramfs in ESP. Are you using or previously used systemD-boot?

Comment: @oldfred  Thank you I moove boot-repair and initramfs on an another partition (as backup) and nothing has gone wrong (I didn't try to boot windows so far). I never used systemd-boot before. Now I can boot into archlinux (Stil a lot to do !)